# Delicious doesn't seem to work anymore, any alternative out there?

Tags: gratis, bookmark, hosted

I've been having issues with [Delicious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicious_%28website%29) and I'm looking for a suitable alternative.

My goal is to send my links from my desktop to my iPad and have it all tidy in one place on the tablet.

- free service
- compatible desktop Windows, iPad, Android

Comment: I have an answer, but there is no button to add an answer. Use Chrome and sign into a Google account. It allows you to synchronize your bookmarks across devices. I believe Apple iCloud also offers that feature as well.

Comment: Cool I'll install Chrome on my iPad and give it a try, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome and sign into a Google account. It allows you to synchronize your bookmarks across devices. I believe Apple iCloud also offers that feature as well for Safari.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to work though (I logged in my Google account on my iPad and bookmarks made on desktop under same account don't show up)

Comment: You have to use Chrome browser and log into the browser using your Google account. You can also use Settings > iCloud > Safari to synch Safari with your desktop through iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Every modern web browser includes the functionality that solves your problem. Except Safari or Microsoft Chrome which are made only for specific sets of devices there is Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome which are doing exactly what you want.

Despite the fact that there is a solution of this matter I feel conscious to say that eitherwise Delicious was not exactly to be used in this way... It was one of the first social media websites which allowed people to publish their bookmarks in bunch or in a series and so get recommendations by the system in conjunction with the public availability of all the bookmarks which in its turn allowed anyone to download them as single .html files and import them to any web browser.

So we can deduce that going to a modern solution (Chrome or Firefox) with cloud infrastructure is the safest step forward that you can do for the moment.